# How to override single template and action in Sonata Admin?

Tags: php, symfony

How to override single template and action in Sonata Admin?

In Symfony 1 this is very simply - get this from cache and copy to folder in backend, but how can i make it in Sonata Admin?

Answer (score 3):

you have to define the new template and the specific action to be overrided .

The documention provide a useful example here :

http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-2/doc/reference/action_show.html#setting-up-a-custom-show-template-very-useful

```
sonata_admin:
    title: Acme
    title_logo: public/img/logo.png
    options:
        title_mode: 'single_image'
    templates:
        # default global templates
        layout:  :sonata:standard_layout.html.twig
        ajax:    SonataAdminBundle::ajax_layout.html.twig
        dashboard: SonataAdminBundle:Core:dashboard.html.twig

        # default actions templates, should extend a global templates
        list:        SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list.html.twig
        show:        SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show.html.twig
        edit:        SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:edit.html.twig
        user_block:  acmeUserBundle:Core:user_block.html.twig
```

a more global doc :

http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-2/doc/reference/templates.html

Answer (score 3):

And if you want to override a single admin template (edit in the example below)

```
app.admin.foo:
    class: AppBundle\Admin\FooAdmin
    arguments: [~, AppBundle\Entity\Foo, AppBundle:FooAdmin]
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: admin, label: Foo }
    calls:
        - [ setTemplate, ['edit', 'AppBundle:Admin/Foo/CRUD:edit.html.twig']]
```